# update a variable of stateful class from another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-state

I'm quite new to flutter and dart.

as an exercise I'm trying to create a Coffeeshop application user interface. here I want to update an integer variable in a StatefulWidget from an other StatefulWidget. I've tried the setState((){})
but It seems that the setState only can update its parent StatefulWidget variables.
I've also tried to use Global variables but nothing change.

the Interesting thing is that when the Keyboard opens, the mentioned variable gets updated!! the keyboard opens from a Textfield inside the app, but I don't know how they are related to each other!!

I want to Update "menu_index" which belongs to MainPage StatefulWidget , from CoffeeType StatefulWidget.

```
List  MenuList = <Widget>[Cappucinno(),Americano()] ;
int menu_index=0;

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyScaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
          Center(
            child: AutoSizeText(
              "Find the best coffee for you!",
              maxLines: 1,
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                hintText: "Search Coffe",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                counter: Offstage(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
          ),
           SizedBox(
             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
             child: CoffeeType(),
           ),
           SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.37,
            child: MenuList[menu_index],
          )
      ],
    ),
        ));
  }
}



class CoffeeType extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  State<CoffeeType> createState() => _CoffeeTypeState();
}

class _CoffeeTypeState extends State<CoffeeType> {


  List type = <String>[
    "Coppuccino",
    "Americano",
    "Latte",
    "Espresso",
    "Arabics",
    "Decaf",
    "Macchiato",
    "Cortado"
  ];
  int selectedindex=0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 8,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  setState((){
                    selectedindex = index;
                    menu_index = selectedindex;
                    print(menu_index);
                    
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                    type[index],
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: selectedindex == index ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please check about state management.. it will make your life easier with problems like this.. either getx https://pub.dev/packages/get, or provider https://pub.dev/packages/provider.. i recommend getx because its easier to learn and has much more functionalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback method to update parent widget.

```dart
class CoffeeType extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int) onTap;
  const CoffeeType({
    Key? key,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<CoffeeType> createState() => _CoffeeTypeState();
}

class _CoffeeTypeState extends State<CoffeeType> {
```

```dart
child: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      selectedindex = index;
      menu_index = selectedindex;
      print(menu_index);
    });
    widget.onTap(menu_index); //here passing tap index to the parent widget
  },
```

And recive here

```dart
child: CoffeeType(
  onTap: (p0) {
    print(p0);
    setState(() {});
  },
),
```

Comment: Thank you Yeasin for your time and reply, It worked perfectly!! would you please make a little explanation? I'm a little confused now...

Comment: Once we setState in a widget It rebuilds itself, means here we were using setState inside `CoffeeType`, therefore it just updates the UI, not parent class. In order to update the parent class we need to call setState on parent class. therefore we are passing a function that will trigger when the tap method happen. and while we use `CoffeeType` now we have a method to notify the parent widget to call setState

Comment: thank you Yeasin , I appreciate your time and answer. it solved my problem. thanks